# running code if length of array is greater than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, indexing

I have 2 arrays of objects. the first has 1 object inside it and the second has 100.

Answer (score 2):

Array.forEach can take three arguments:

element, index, array

Try getting in the array as well and check for its length like below:

```
var myItems = o.getAggregation("ooo")[0].getItems();
myItems.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    if(array.length > 1) {/*do whatever*/}
})
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) the reference and the first example shows you taking in an array argument.

Updating with an example:

```
function demo(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    if(array.length === 1) {
      console.log("Array with one element: ", array);
    } else {
      console.log("Array with three elements, so gets called thrice: ", array);
    }
  });
}

var myItems = ["1"];
demo(myItems);
myItems = ["1","2","3"];
demo(myItems);
```

And here's how the output looks like:

```
Array with one element:  [ '1' ]
Array with three elements, so gets called thrice:  [ '1', '2', '3' ]
Array with three elements, so gets called thrice:  [ '1', '2', '3' ]
Array with three elements, so gets called thrice:  [ '1', '2', '3' ]
```

Comment: it didnt work for me..could you please use the code above

Comment: i tried this and it only checked if the 1st array had more than one object. it didnt check the second array.